# Can't initialise variable as ArrayList.clone()

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Trying to create a clone of `ArrayList` `players`. I want to clone it entirely (the `ArrayList` including its contents).

**Activity.kt**

```
lateinit var playersinfo: PlayersInfo
lateinit var players: ArrayList<Player>
lateinit var tempPlayers: ArrayList<Player>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

val intent = intent
playersinfo = intent.getParcelableExtra<PlayersInfo>("playersinfo")
players = playersinfo.players
var tempPlayers: ArrayList<Player> = players.clone() // RETURNS ERROR
players.forEach { tempPlayers.add(it)}
```

`tempPlayers` initialisation returns this error: [image]

**Player.kt**

```
@Parcelize
data class Player (
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val gender: String
): Parcelable

@Parcelize
class PlayersInfo(
    val players: ArrayList<@RawValue Player>, val anyBelow18: Boolean = players.any { player -> player.age < 18 },
    var location: String = "Other"
): Parcelable {

}
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I actually don't understand what the confusion is. `#clone()` returns `Any`, not `ArrayList<Player>` so you obviously need to cast.

Comment: So what's the point of cloning if you have to create the cloned array by doing `players.forEach { tempPlayers.add(it)}` anyway?

Comment: In Java you would write `List<Player> tempPlayers = new ArrayList<>(players);`.  The `clone()` method is not particularly useful for generic collections because casting to a generic type gives a compiler error.

Comment: "So what's the point of cloning if you have to create the cloned array by doing players.forEach { tempPlayers.add(it)} anyway?" Don't blame Kotlin when you do unnecessary stuff. I don't know why you've added it, but you don't need that.

Comment: @StephenC The Kotlin equivalent would be `tempPlayers = ArrayList(players)` (I removed `var` and `type`, because that would shadow an existing property (that is why `var` is highlighted in OPs code))

Comment: Thanks @Tom `tempPlayers = ArrayList(players)` is what I was seeking. When would `clone()` be useful?